# Solenoid interchangeable

Tags: honda, electrical, motorcycle, solenoid

In regards to solenoids being basically interchangeable, does the function of the 4 contact plug that connects it provide different functions on different solenoids. Generally speaking, will the same looking part function the same.

I have an '83 Honda Nighthawk CB550

Comment: Writing about an 83 Honda nighthawk CB550 BTW.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!